# How to fix Array Errors and ArrayStoreException when filling in a 2-d array with a method

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods, compiler-errors

I have pasted my code below. 
The array does give me the random numbers, however at the end of the array the errors pop up and I have been unable to fix the errors.
The goal is to produce an array with 2 columns and n amount of rows. randomized ints will fill in the array. 
I have a main in which I've created a 2-d array to hold the values, and I am using the Array.fill() method to call on a method I made *randArray* that makes the actual array with randomized ints.

The problem is once the code has run, it gives me a few errors that I haven't been able to get rid of. These are the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: [[I
at java.base/java.util.Arrays.fill(Arrays.java:3639)
at Animal.main(Animal.java:22)
```

Things I have tried:

- change the range to range-1
- changing the rows to rows-1
- changing the *i* and *j* values inside the second method
- throwing my textbook into the garbage where it belongs

What direction should I be going in? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random; //import library for generating random numbers

//Creating an array with 2 columns, the number of rows are based on user input and the numbers
//inside the array are randomized between 0 and x with user giving x

public class Animal {

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of rows: ");
        int numNodes = input.nextInt();    //this will be the number of rows in the array

        System.out.println("Enter the maximum:  ");
        double max = input.nextDouble();    //array data is inside this range 


        int[][] something = new int [numNodes][];
        Arrays.fill(something, randArray(numNodes,max));



  //    System.out.println("The rows are: " + arrayMade(numNodes,networkSize)); //testing the array to see if it works

       System.out.println(something);
    }

/** Creating an array to fill the random array with random ints
 * 
 * @param numRows the number of rows the array will have
 * @param range the maximum for a value in the array
 * @return randArray returns a randomized filled in 2-d array
 */

public static int[][] randArray (int numRows, double range)    //method to make the array 
    { 
        int[][] randArray = new int[numRows+1][2];                         
        Random rand = new Random(); 

        int count = numRows-1;
        int i = 0;

     while(i < count){  //this loops based on how many rows there are

        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            randArray[i][0] = rand.nextInt((int)range) ;  // random integer from 0 to max
            randArray[i][1] = rand.nextInt((int)range) ;

        System.out.println(randArray[i][0] + "   " + randArray[i][1]); //test line
        i++;

        }//end for-loop


      }//end while-loop

        return randArray;
    }//end arrayMade


}//end class
```

Comment: Maybe `int[][] something = new int [numNodes][2];`

Comment: Why is range a double then forced to be an int ?

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)` - why ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html - *Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects.*

Comment: @ScaryWombat I did that (changing the nodes and range from double to int) and I did have my fingers crossed however it still gave me the same error

Comment: Arrays.fill is used to `fill` an array with a single value.  You can just use `something = randArray(numNodes,max);`

Comment: I didn't realize that it was for a single value, thanks for explaining, I did what you suggested and it worked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't have to use `Arrays.fill` , just assign the return value of your `randArray` function to the 2d array.

```java
int[][] something = randArray(numNodes, max);
```

PS: you need a way to print the 2d array to the console, using `System.out.println(something)` will output unexpected result.

Also, remove the `for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)` loop, it's really unnecessary.

Here's the final code you can refer to:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

//Creating an array with 2 columns, the number of rows are based on user input and the numbers
//inside the array are randomized between 0 and x with user giving x

public class Animal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of rows: ");
        int numNodes = input.nextInt();    //this will be the number of rows in the array

        System.out.println("Enter the maximum:  ");
        int max = input.nextInt();    //array data is inside this range


        int[][] something = randArray(numNodes, max);


        //    System.out.println("The rows are: " + arrayMade(numNodes,networkSize)); //testing the array to see if it works

        System.out.println(something);
    }

    /**
     * Creating an array to fill the random array with random ints
     *
     * @param numRows the number of rows the array will have
     * @param range   the maximum for a value in the array
     * @return randArray returns a randomized filled in 2-d array
     */

    public static int[][] randArray(int numRows, int range)    //method to make the array
    {
        int[][] randArray = new int[numRows + 1][2];
        Random rand = new Random();

        int count = numRows - 1;
        int i = 0;

        while (i < count) {  //this loops based on how many rows there are

            randArray[i][0] = rand.nextInt(range);  // random integer from 0 to max
            randArray[i][1] = rand.nextInt(range);

            System.out.println(randArray[i][0] + "   " + randArray[i][1]); //test line
            i++;

        }//end while-loop

        return randArray;
    }//end arrayMade


}//end class
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes total sense, I didn't think of calling the method like, I was so focused on using .fill. I checked and using prinln(something) gives the location of the array and not the contents, and the for loop is also redundant so I have deleted that as well. Thanks again mate!

Comment: You're welcome @Zafa . Is there any reason for that downvote? Anyone?